# QueryBuilder with generic type

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to build a query for dynamic types of fields. Most of the fields are Strings but actually one is an Instant. I'm in the `toPredicate()` method of an Spring Data JPA `Specification`

```java
Expression key = root.get("someDynamicFieldname");
// with dynamic field values and field types:
String value1 = "abc";
Instant value2 = Instant.now();
```

Now I need to build the expression for this field with a generic type for the value. I'm searching for something like that:

```java
// <TYPE???> value;
// value = value1;
// value = value2;
Expression<Boolean> expression = criteriaBuilder.lessThan(key, value);
```

How can this be achieved?

I already tried `ParameterExpression` but in the `Specification` I have no way to set the parameter value.

Comment: You tried with `Object`?

Comment: Yes, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. `Comparable` is the working type.

```java
Comparable value;
value = "abc";
value = Instant.now();
Expression<Boolean> expression = criteriaBuilder.lessThan(key, value);
```

Comment: You may want to make sure that JPA knows how to handle `java.time` data types; if an object is only `Comparable`, JPA may resort to doing the comparisons in Java instead of the DB. See e.g. [here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-java-8-date-and-time-jsr310/).

Comment: Interesting. Is this still relevant for Spring Boot 2.0? Hibernate 5.2 supports it, so I think it's not needed(?)